# Div 100% width and a margin

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to put a left and right margin on something that is also 100% width. I was using the box-sizing method which I was hoping would make it say 100% including the margin but it does 100% PLUS the margin, meaning I have a vertical scroll bar.

It's demonstrated here:

http://jsbin.com/xomocitono/1

```
  <div id="main">
    Test
  </div>

#main {width: 100%; margin-left: 100px; margin-right: 100px; background: red;}
```

In my own particular situation I can't use the following:

1. Padding instead, because even though it works how I want (in terms of 100% width) the padding covers the links below whereas the margin doesn't.
2. CSS Calc (it isn't as cross browser as I was hoping)
3. Fixed width #main, because I want it to be fluid, just with a margin either side.

Do I have any other options?

Comment: Wrap it up with another `div` and give this one `padding` to work as the `margin` for the `div` within it.

Comment: `CSS Calc (it isn't as cross browser as I was hoping)` - what are you supporting?

Comment: Why not give it less than `100%`? if it stays fluid, do the exact margins matter?

Comment: I'm hoping to use IE8+. It would be ideal to have exact margins but it isn't the end of the world I guess. I'm not sure how you mean @MelanciaUK

Comment: @Jimmy you don't have to give width when are using margin-left and margin-right.

Comment: @madhu Oh gosh! You've solved it! Please add it as an answer so I can accept

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to give **width** when you are using **margin-left** and **margin-right**.

Try This:

```
#main
{
 margin-left: 10%;
 margin-right: 10%;
 background: red;
}
```